# RemotingServices.IsObjectOutOfAppDomain when it will return false?

Tags: c#, .net, remoting

As per Remote Object definition- Any object outside the application domain of the caller should be considered remote.

[`RemotingServices.IsObjectOutOfAppDomain`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.remotingservices.isobjectoutofappdomain%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)- returns false if remote object resides in the same app domain.

In the MSDN article [Microsoft .NET Remoting: A Technical Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973857.aspx#hawkremoting_topic3) I
found the following statement (in the paragraph "Proxy Objects") about
method calls on remote objects:

> ...the [method] call is examined to determine if it is a valid method
>   of the remote object and if an instance of the remote object resides in
>   the same application domain as the proxy. If this is true, a simple
>   method call is routed to the actual object.

So I am surprised when the remote object and proxy will reside in the same app domain.

sample example:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.Remoting;
using System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels;
using System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Tcp;

namespace RemotingSamples
{
public class HelloServer : MarshalByRefObject
{
public HelloServer()
{
Console.WriteLine("HelloServer activated");
}
public String HelloMethod(String name)
{
return "Hi there " + name;
}
}
public class Server
{
public static int Main(string [] args)
{
// server code
ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(new TcpChannel(8085));
RemotingConfiguration.RegisterWellKnownServiceType(
typeof(HelloServer), "SayHelloSingleton",
WellKnownObjectMode.Singleton);

// client code
HelloServer obj = HelloServer)Activator.GetObject(
typeof(HelloServer), "tcp://localhost:8085/SayHelloSingleton");

System.Console.WriteLine(
"IsTransparentProxy={0}, IsOutOfAppDomain={1}",
RemotingServices.IsTransparentProxy(obj),
RemotingServices.IsObjectOutOfAppDomain(obj));
Console.WriteLine(obj.HelloMethod("server"));
return 0;
}
}
}
```

Comment: I had an interesting case not long ago.

I had a client - server app, where servers could be then be 'clients' of another server. I wanted to write code that checks that a server is not contacting 'itself'. Ran into this post. Thought I'd share since it could be related..

Answer (score 0):

Well, one obvious case when it will return false is when the object isn't a proxy, but is a regular .NET object in the local domain (no remoting involved).

I don't understand the MSDN note fully, either ;-p